# Fetch complete contact detail from ContactsContract.Profile

Tags: android, contacts, profile

I am looking to fetch complete contact detail of the owner (me profile - e.g. in Nexus). I found ContactsContract.Profile API which is available for API v14+.

I am successfully able to get display name, corresponding to which i further require contact number. To do all this, i am using following code

```
private void getSelfSimNumber() {

        String displayName = null;

        try {
            Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                    null);
            int count = c.getCount();
            boolean b = c.moveToFirst();
            int position = c.getPosition();
            if (count == 1 && position == 0) {
                displayName = c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                    Cursor pCur = this.getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { displayName },
                            null);

                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String ret = c.getString(0);
                        String ret1 = c.getString(1);
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

The problem is I am unable to fetch contact number of "me" profile. If, suppose, I have total 3 contacts (including "me" profile) then total contacts available i am getting is only 2. The system is perhaps not considering "me" profile as a contact.

How to solve this problem and fetch contact number of "me" profile?

Thanks